# Twitter style following-follower table in SQL

Tags: sql, database, twitter-follow

I have a basic follower/following table in mySQL which looks like this.

```
id      user_id     follower_id
1           userA       userB
2           userC       userA
3           userA       userC
4           userB       userC
5           userB       userA
```

I checked these topics but couldnt find what I need

[database design for 'followers' and 'followings'?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4895809/database-design-for-followers-and-followings)

[SQL Following and Followers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15495570/sql-following-and-followers)

What I need is to have a system like this:

Assume we are userB ( we follow userA, we are followed by userC and userA)

I like to return a result that includes this follower/following state. For example for userB:

```
id      followedBy     areWeFollowing
1           userA       1
2           userC       0
```

Thanks for your help!

arda

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With this query to find if who you follow, follow you too.

```
SELECT ff1.follower_id as followedBy,
(
   select count(follower_id) 
   from follower_following as ff2 
   where ff2.user_id = ff1.follower_id 
   and ff2.follower_id = ff1.user_id 
) as areWeFollowing 
FROM follower_following as ff1  
where user_id = 'userB';
```