# Twitter style following-follower table in SQL-2

Tags: sql, database, twitter-follow

Addition to this [Twitter style following-follower table in SQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16618631/twitter-style-following-follower-table-in-sql)

In the upper example I was able to return the query for "if userB is following the other users who follows him"

I need a simpler thing now. I tried to modify the original code without any luck. I simply need "if userB is following or not any of the users , regardless if they follow him. Currently it returns null for people who dont follow that particular user.

This is the sample table for users

```
id      user_id     
1           userA     
2           userB     
3           userC      
4           userD      
5           userE
```

This is the sample table for follows

```
id      user_id     follower_id
1           userA       userB
2           userD       userB
```

I like to return a result that includes this follower/following state. For example for userB (he follows A and D but not C and E:

```
id      followedBy     areWeFollowing
1           userA       1
2           userB       0
3           userC       0
4           userD       1
5           userE       0
```

Thanks for your help!

arda

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can even take a count also from second table for this situation -

```
select id,user_id, ( select count(*) 
                       from follows 
                      where follows.user_id = users.user_id
                        and follows.follower_id = 'userB') as areWeFollowing
from users
```

Comment: Yes sir! 
PS:"AS" areWeFollowing from users

Comment: @ardavar Thanks for correcting me.
actually I am working on Oracle database and `as` is not compulsary in it so that's why missed this.